# Syntax to Check for Null in DateTime in Linq Results

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, datatable

I have a strong typed datatable with two datetime fields. The table is filled with data from a SQL Server. The datetime fields in the SQL Server allows for nulls. In the ADO call to the DB, I was able to trap the nulls.

But now I'm making a Linq call against the datatable and I can't find a syntax that will let me trap the null in the datetime field.

```
var results = (from r in dsReleases.dtReleases
    where r.ReleaseNumber == Convert.ToInt32(theRelease)
    select r
).FirstOrDefault();

GetTheDeliveryData(results.Delivery.ToString());

lbReleaseNumber.Text = results.ReleaseNumber.ToString();
lbStartDate.Text = results.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
lbEndDate.Text = results.EndDate.ToShortDateString();
lbQuantity.Text = results.ReleaseQuantity.ToString();
lbStatus.Text = results.Status;
```

The error is on writing the start and end dates to the label field. Any suggestions on how to test that datetime field for null?

I tried this;

```
lbStartDate.Text = results.StartDate == null ? "": results.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
```

and got an error of

> The column 'StartDate' in table dtReleases is DBNull.

So I tried this;

```
lbStartDate.Text = results.StartDate ==  DBNull.Value ? "": results.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
```

But that won't compile, it gives an error of

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DBNull'.

This syntax compiles, but crashes while running;

```
lbStartDate.Text = DBNull.Value.Equals(results.StartDate) ? "": results.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
```

It leads me back to this error,

> The value for column 'StartDate' in table 'dtReleases' is DBNull.

Comment: If the column is nullable in your database, you should have your model *also* indicate that the column is nullable.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is     variable = condition ? ConditionValue : else value;         that would be the syntax and thats also why it didn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Your `StartDate` property in your object needs to be of type `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`. As in:

`public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you the solution:

> So I tried this; lbStartDate.Text = results.StartDate == DBNull.Value ? "": results.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
>
> But that won't compile, it gives an error of "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DBNull'."

It will not work because `results.StartDate` is a non nullable datetime so it must always have a value. It is not optional (nullable). But you are trying to compare it to a `DBNull` so the compiler is complaining that it does not know how to do that. Make `results.StartDate` nullable and it will work.

Comment: Yoshi, I'm am still learning linq. How do I make results.StartDate nullable?

Comment: `public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }` the question mark is a shorthand. Or you can do `public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what type of collection DtReleases is. Results will be of the same type as any element in DtReleases.

If you look at the definition of DtReleases, you will see that every element in DtReleases is an object of a type that contains a property StartDate.

StartDate is probably either a DateTime, or a DateTime? (alternative: `Nullable<DateTime>`

If it really is a DateTime, you can be assured that if your query works at runtime your results contains a DateTime.

If it is a DateTime? you should check whether it has a value or not before using it. Every nullable type has properties HasValue and Value:

```
if (results.StartDate.HasValue)
{
    lbStartDate.Text = results.StartData.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
else
{
    lsStartDate.Text = null;
}
```

The newer versions of C# have a shorthand for this:

```
lbStartDate.Text = results.StartDate?.ToShortDateString();
```

If start date has a value, then the result of the expression will be this value ToShortDateString. else the result of the expression will be null.

See [C# Null Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dn986595.aspx)

Comment: "You didn't specify what type of collection DtReleases is." It's a typed datatable in a dataset.

Comment: Yes it is, But I can't see whether StartDate is a DateTime or a nullable DateTime, which is significant in diagnosing your problem